# Where can I find graded readers for French?

Tags: reading, electronic-resources, physical-resources, french, graded-readers

Graded readers are a good type of material for extensive reading. But how do you find graded readers in French? 
The English Wikipedia article [graded reader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_reader) has no link to the same concept in the French Wikipedia (see the "Languages" section in the left-hand menu).

So are there any graded readers in French and how can I find them?

Answer (score 6):

In order to find graded readers in French, you need to look for "**[livres en] français facile**" ("[books in] easy French"). However, not all books that are marked as "français facile" are graded readers for learners of French as a foreign language. If you find something like FLE (français langue étrangère: French as a foreign language) or a level indication such as A2 on the cover, then you can be certain you have a graded reader for learners of French.

There are several collections of graded readers, for example:

- LFF (Lire en français facille) is a series published by Hachette. It contains several "collections" of books for the levels A1, A2, B1 and B2:

  - The [Collection classique](http://www.lire-en-francais-facile.com/collection-classique) contains simplified and abridged versions of classics such as *Le tour du Monde en 80 jours*, * Sans famille* and *Les Misérables*.
  - The [Collection fiction](http://www.lire-en-francais-facile.com/collection-fiction) contains previously unpublished stories.
  - The [Collection Albert et Folio](http://www.lire-en-francais-facile.com/albert-et-folio) is squarely aimed at children.
- CLE International has a series of graded readers called [Lectures CLE en français facile](https://www.cle-international.com/collection/lectures-cle-en-francais-facile/). It contains titles for A1, A2 and B1. For example, *Voyage au centre de la terre* (A1), *Les misérables* (level A2), *Germinal* (B1) and many other titles.
- The CI Bookshop has a series of [easy readers "for all levels"](https://www.thecibookshop.com/en/easy-readers/french/). Many of these are also available as e-books. These books are aimed at children and will not necessarily appeal to adult readers.

In 2014, the French organisation Livre et lecture en Bretagne published a PDF file entitled [Choix de livres « faciles à lire »](https://www.livrelecturebretagne.fr/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Livret_kit_facile_lire.pdf). Most of these titles are aimed at native speakers who don't read well; these books may be the next step after reading the graded readers listed above.